# Pagination not working in the main index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

So my link to show the older posts is not displaying on my main blog page http://surechamp.com/blog/ it's displaying fine in my archive.php so I'm not sure why it's not working with the index.php. I'm using underscores as my base theme to work off of. This is my code:

```
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php _s_paging_nav(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>


    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically run paging navigation outside the loop and test if there will be a previous or next link shown:

```
<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <?php if($wp_query->get('paged') || $wp_query->get('paged') > 1): ?>
        <a class="loadPrev" href="<?php previous_posts(); ?>">prev</a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($next_url = next_posts($wp_query->max_num_pages, false)): ?>
        <a class="loadNext" href="<?php echo $next_url; ?>">next</a>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```